# c++ fstream obj rollback after using in istream_iterator

Tags: c++, io, fstream, istream-iterator

How to reset iterator state or use `fstream` obj, which was in use by `istream_iterator`, in other `istream_iterator`. I tried `seekp(ios_base::begin)` and `clear()` methods on `fstream` obj but this doesn't  do any affect.

```
main(){
    fstream ofs{"219.txt"};
    fstream ofstl{"219-.txt"};

    ofstream rezult{"219-rezult.txt"};

    istream_iterator<string> begf{ofs};
    istream_iterator<string> begs{ofstl};
    istream_iterator<string> end;

    ostream_iterator<string> outr{rezult, "\n"};

    merge(begf, end, begs, end, outr);    // using iterators

    ofs.seekp(ios_base::beg);       // does not affect
    ofs.clear();                    // does not affect

    while(begf!=end){
        cout<<*begf;                // work only once
        begf++;
    }

    istream_iterator<string> begff{ofs};        // new iterator
    while(begff!=end){
        cout<<*begff;               // dont work even once
        begff++;
    }
}
```

Upd:
If i use

```
ofs.clear();
ofs.seekp(ios_base::beg);
```

and then continue to use same `istream_iterator` first and second dereference give same value, so need to use

```
begf++;
```

to skip duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `clear` before `seekp`, as there are fail and/or eof bits which are not handled by `seekp`

```
ofs.clear();
ofs.seekp(ios_base::beg);
```